# 2 jQuery scripts conflicting

Tags: jquery, css, fancybox, conflict, stoppropagation

I've got a button linking to fancybox and another that toggles a hidden contact form.
They both work alone but I can't get the fancybox to work when they're together. I think
it might have something to to do with the stopPropagation in my script? Does anyone have any idea what I can do to stop them conflicting?

```
<div class="buttoncont">
        <div class="innercont">
        <div class="thanks" style="display:none;"><p>Thanks for contacting class</p></div>
            <div class="social">
                <!— FANCYBOX BUTTON LINK —>
                <div class="fancybox-media" href="http://vimeo.com/9532951" rel="media-gallery">
                <a class="btn"> <span class="playarrow"></span><span>watch fancybox preview</span></a></div>
                    <!— FANCYBOX BUTTON LINK END—>
                <!— CONTACT US LINK —>  
                <a class="btn2" href="#innercont" id='link'><span class="contactbbl"></span><span>contact us</span></a>
                    <!— CONTACT US LINK END —> 
            </div>
<div id="subscribe-pop”><p>DIV POPUP TRIGGERED FROM CONTACT US LINK</p></div>

<div id="badge1”>
    <a href="http://www.site1.com"><img class="badge1" src="images/badge1.png" height="auto" width="100%"></a>
</div>
<div id=“badge2”>
        <a href="http://www.site2.com"><img class="badge2” src="images/badge2.png" height="auto" width="100%"></a>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

CONTACT FORM SCRIPT

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('html').click(function() {
    $('#subscribe-pop').hide();
    $('.thanks').hide(); 
 });

 $(‘.innercont’).click(function(e){
     e.stopPropagation();
 });

$('#link').click(function(e) {
 $('#subscribe-pop').toggle();
 });

$('#mc_embed_signup .button').click(function(e) { 
 $('#subscribe-pop').hide(); 
 $('.thanks').toggle(); 
 });

 $('#mc_embed_signup .cancel').click(function(e) { 
 $('#subscribe-pop').hide(); 

 });

$('.thanks').click(function() { 
 $('.thanks').hide(); 
 });

</script>
```

FANCY BOX SCRIPT

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.fancybox-media')
                .attr('rel', 'media-gallery')
                .fancybox({
                    padding: 0,
                    openEffect : 'none',
                    closeEffect : 'none',
                    prevEffect : 'none',
                    nextEffect : 'none',
                    arrows : false,
                    helpers : {
                        media : {},
                        buttons : {}
                    }
                });
                        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be because of Jquery conflict .

There are always chances of conflict between two javascript libraries

Try

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

Now you can use `$j` instead of `$` in your jquery code.

[jquery conflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Comment: Thanks, I added the `var $j = jQuery.noConflict();` at the beginning of my jquery and changed all the `$` to `$j` but it didn't work..

Comment: Do you know of another method I might be able to use for my show/hide contact form to avoid them conflicting?